# Sticky navigation not adding active links correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, navigation

I'm trying to implement a navigation. I have used [this code](https://codepen.io/joxmar/pen/NqqMEg) to do the same.

```
<nav>
<ul id="mainNav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>    
  </ul>
</nav>
<section id="home"><h2>Home</h2></section>
<section id="work" data-sr><h2>Work</h2></section>
<section id="about"><h2>About</h2></section>
<section id="contact"><h2>Contact</h2></section>

// Cache selectors

var lastId,
 topMenu = $("#mainNav"),
 topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+1,
 // All list items
 menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
 // Anchors corresponding to menu items
 scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
   var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
    if (item.length) { return item; }
 });

// Bind click handler to menu items
// so we can get a fancy scroll animation
menuItems.click(function(e){
  var href = $(this).attr("href"),
      offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
  $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
      scrollTop: offsetTop
  }, 850);
  e.preventDefault();
});
$(window).scroll(function(){
   // Get container scroll position
   var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

   // Get id of current scroll item
   var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
     if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
       return this;
   });
   // Get the id of the current element
   cur = cur[cur.length-1];
   var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

   if (lastId !== id) {
       lastId = id;
       // Set/remove active class
       menuItems
         .parent().removeClass("active")
         .end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("active");
   }                   
});
```

The requirement :- I want the navigation to have links which can be swapped as per the requirement.

The issue :- In the above codepen when I swap the links, it does not add the active classes properly. If I swap the navigation links AND the section link also then only it works well.
For example, if my navigation has HOME, WORK, ABOUT and CONTACT. Then I should be able to swap the position of the work link with the contact link and still my sticky navigation SHOULD add the active classes correctly WITHOUT shifting their respective sections.

Please help me achieve the above scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code should solve your problem.

```
// Cache selectors
var lastId,
 topMenu = $("#mainNav"),
 topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+1,
 // All list items
 menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
 // Anchors corresponding to menu items
 scrollItems = $('section');

// Bind click handler to menu items
// so we can get a fancy scroll animation
menuItems.click(function(e){
  var href = $(this).attr("href"),
      offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
  $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
      scrollTop: offsetTop
  }, 850);
  e.preventDefault();
  setActiveNav(href);
});

function setActiveNav(href) {
  menuItems.each((index, menu) => {
    if(menu.hash === href) {
      $(menu).parent().addClass('active');
    } else {
      $(menu).parent().removeClass('active');
    }
  });
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
   // Get container scroll position
   var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop();


   // Get id of current scroll item
   var cur = scrollItems.toArray().findIndex(item => {
    return (item.offsetTop >= fromTop);
});
   // Get the id of the current element
   var id = cur && cur > -1 ? scrollItems[cur].id : "";

   if (lastId !== id) {
       lastId = id;
       // Set/remove active class
       menuItems
         .parent().removeClass("active")
         .end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("active");
   }
});
```

Structuring your functionalities in separate functions will solve future maintenance overheads.

Mostly the issues are with structuring, element index and position.

Comment: Hi,Can you please make this work on scroll too like it is in the codepen?

Comment: @amy This is the codepen I've used [https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eLqdyX. Please have a look at it and let me know what is your exact requirement.

Comment: Yes.Thank you for making it work on click.But I want the same behavior(of adding active class)  on scroll too.Like if you scroll,then the particular sections will get highlighted (the same way which it is working in the codepen i posted)

Comment: @amy I've updated the code to work for both scroll and click functions. Please check and let me know any changes required.

Comment: 2 things - 1 .It refuses to detect the id of when the index becomes 0.And secondly,when the index is -1 ,it gives me a  Cannot read property 'id' of undefined error

Comment: 1 .It refuses to detect the id of when the index becomes 0.You can check on your codepen.Just scroll and you will see the issue that it is not taking the id when cur=0 .Thank you soooo much!So the home link does not get highlighted!

Comment: @amy And finally I've updated the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BqBdKL). Please do verify and if any clarifications needed, don't hesitate to reach out :)

Comment: I am really grateful for your help.Now the sticky is working perfectly on scroll but on click,the active classes are getting added with some lag.For example,when I am going from  work link to home,the active class does not get added properly.:(

Comment: Yeah , I too noticed that. That is because we're using scroll event without any timeout. so the scroll event gets called multiple times as we scroll. Try adding some timeout to solve it.

Comment: @amy some moderator gonna come and move our comments to chat saying 'comments are not for extended discussion' :P